# How to traverse an object inside another object? Javascript. React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I have the following JSON that comes to me from the backend which I want to go through the 'assigned_permissions' field

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSuar.png)

It turns out that 'assigned permissions' is an object that sits inside multiple objects. So far I have done the following:

```
Object.entries(dataUserProfile.permissions[dataOriginSelect].permissions)
    .map(([key, value]) => (
      console.log("value", value.assigned_permissions)
    ))
```

dataOriginSelect is a useState that references the object I am selecting. The console.log gives me the following:

```
value {add: false, edit: false, delete: false, query: true, download: false, …}
```

I get the object in question, now it turns out that I have to iterate through it, do I have to implement 'Object.entries' again?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't have to implement Object.entries, it's part of every modern browser and yes it's the way to go.

Comment: What should I use to loop through objects?

Comment: `Object.entries`?  you mentioned it yourself. What are you actually stuck on?

Comment: Any! Oh, I was able to do it with this:

`Object.entries(dataUserProfile.permissions[dataOriginSelect].permissions)
     .map(([key, value]) => (
       Object.entries(value.assigned_permissions)
       .map(([key, value]) => (
         console.log("key",key)
         console.log("value",value)
       ))
     ))`

Comment: glad you figured it out, but fwiw this is not a good use of `.map` and your code might be more readable with a simple `for(..of..)` loop

Comment: Could you show me an example?